# How to locate a element <span> inside another <span> in Xpath?

Tags: html, xml, google-apps-script, xpath, google-sheets

I am learning to use API to import data to my google sheet. As a newbie in coding, I am not familiar in using Xpath to locate the element I wish to capture. Here's my problem, I wish to api the dividend value from https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/spfi/dividend-history  and after I inspect the elements, I found the Xpath structure is

> 

```
  <span class="dividend-history__summary-item__label">Annual Dividend</span>
  <span class="dividend-history__summary-item__value">$<span>0.12</span></span>
```

I tried using

> //*[@class='dividend-history__summary-item__value']

to locate, which turns out the result of '$' sign only. And then I further tried

> //*[@class='dividend-history__summary-item__value']/following-sibling::/text()

where no results is given.

May anyone generous to teach me, how do I locate the "0.12" from this Xpath structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first XPath,

```
//*[@class='dividend-history__summary-item__value']
```

selects

```
<span class="dividend-history__summary-item__value">$<span>0.12</span></span>
```

which has a string value of `$0.12`.  It is odd that you're seeing only `$` be returned; it suggests that there is a `/text()` step is being automatically added to your XPath as `$` is the only text node child of the above `span`.

---

Your second XPath,

```
//*[@class='dividend-history__summary-item__value']/following-sibling::/text()
```

is syntactically incorrect.  Perhaps you meant this XPath

```
//*[@class='dividend-history__summary-item__value']/following-sibling::text()
```

which would look to select a text node following this `span`,

```
<span class="dividend-history__summary-item__value">$<span>0.12</span></span>
```

but would find none.

---

This XPath,

```
//span[@class='dividend-history__summary-item__value']/span
```

will select

```
<span>0.12</span>
```

which has a string value of `0.12`, as requested.

Comment: Thank you, kjhughes. I tried your way and now further understand the concept how to locate an element. However, my google sheet still did not give out a correct outcome by using importxml; isn't it because the string itself is a dynamic data, for example, js?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to debug further.   If it's an `importxml()` issue as you suspect, perhaps peruse [these Q/A](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=google+spreadsheet+xpath%20site:stackoverflow.com)  to see if anything there helps.

Comment: Note that `<span class="dividend-history__summary-item__value">`  does not appear  via "View source" in the form that you state in your question.   It does appear when the DOM is inspected via a browser debugger.  This suggests that the value is populated dynamically in the browser and thus may not be available at the time `importxml()` looks at it.  Focus your search on seeing if `importxml()` can read the results of JavaScript execution.  If it cannot, you may have to use another technology that can execute the page's JavaScript before scrapping.